# Let $L$ be the brach of $\log z$ in $D$ that satisfies $L(e)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\mathbb{C}-\{z|z=0 \text{ or } z=e^{t+it}, -\infty < t < \infty \}$ and let $L$ be the brach of $\log z$ in $D$ that satisfies $L(e)=1$. Determine:

i) $L(e^6)$

ii) $L(-e^{-8})$

iii) $L(ie^{i k})$ for any integer $k$.

What is the range of $L$?

I know that $L$ must be continuous and that $e^{L(z)}=z$, from there I can only get $e^{L(e^6)}=e^6$ so $L(e^6)-6=2k\pi i$...so what?

Is it true that $L$ must be of the form $\ln|z|+i\text{arg}z$ where  $\text{arg}z$ is an argument of $z$?

Comment: It is true that $L(e^z) = z + 2\pi i k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. But it requires to look at the geometry of $D$ in order to pinpoint which $k$ should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observation.** Let $\Gamma = \{0\}\cup\{e^{t+it} : t \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Then it is easy to see that

$$ \Gamma \cap \mathbb{R} = \{0\} \cup \{ (-1)^k e^{k\pi} : k \in \mathbb{Z} \}. $$

In particular, we always have

$$ (e^{2k\pi}, e^{2(k+1)\pi}) \subset D, \qquad (-e^{(2k-1)\pi}, -e^{(2k+1)\pi}) \subset D. $$

---

(i) Since $[e,e^6] \subset (e^0, e^{2\pi})$, this line segment stays within $D$. So we have

$$L(e^6) = L(1) + \int_{e}^{e^6} \frac{dx}{x} = 6. $$

(ii) You need one and a half clockwise rotation in order to reach $-e^{-8}$ from $e$.

Indeed, consider the curve $\alpha(t) = e^{1-(t+it)}$ for $t \in [0,3\pi]$. This curve stays within $D$ and ends at the point $\alpha(3\pi) = -e^{1-3\pi}$. Since $\beta = [-e^{1-3\pi}, -e^{-8}] \subset (-e^{-3\pi}, e^{-\pi})$, the line segment $\beta$ also stays within $D$. So it follows that

$$ L(-e^{-8}) = L(e) + \int_{\alpha \cup \beta} \frac{dz}{z} = -8-3\pi i. $$

(iii) As we see in the picture below, we have to travel clockwise to reach any point on the unit circle except $1 \in \Gamma$.

$\hspace{8em}$ [image: $\Gamma$ and the unit circle]

This tells that we have $L(e^{i\theta}) = i\theta$ if $\theta \in (-2\pi, 0)$. Then (iii) can be easily answered from this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is it true that $L(e^6) = L(1) + \int_{e}^{e^6} \frac{dx}{x}$?

Comment: @Lotte, Allow me to ask back, but what is the definition of 'a branch of logarithm' you are using? The explanation definitely depends on it, and in fact clarifying this definition does help answer your question.

Comment: $L$ is a brach of log if $L$ is continous and $e^{L(z)}=z$

Comment: @Lotte, By the inverse function theorem, such $L$ is always differentiable and its derivative can be computed as $$ L'(z) = \frac{1}{e^{L(z)}} = \frac{1}{z}. $$ So by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $L(z)$ can be retrieved by integrating $L'(z) = \frac{1}{z}$. (Of course, both IFT and FToC mentioned here are versions that hold for complex analysis.)